# Get all articles that a certain user hasn't commented on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have three models: Article, Comment, User.

A user can comment on an article.

Here's how to get all articles where there's no comment at all, but I only want those that a certain user has *not* commented on yet:

```
Article.includes(:comments).where(:comments => { :id => nil })
```

**Update**

```
class Article
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many : comments
end
```

Comment: Can you post the associations between the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :no_user_comments, ->(id) { joins(:comments).where('comments.user_id NOT IN (?)', id) }
end
```

You can then pass:

```
@articles = Article.no_user_comments @user.id
```

or

```
@articles = Article.no_user_comments [@user.id, "15", "25"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had to face the same issue, but the answers provided don’t seem to be working:

```
@articles = Article.joins(:comments).where.not(comments: {user_id: @user.id})
```

or the various different variants, will also return articles commented by the user if they where commented also by other users.
E.g. Article1: commentA by user1, commentB by user2

I’ve found this truly inelegant solution:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :users, through: :comments  #create a many-to-many relations
end
```

and

```
@articles = Article.joins(:comments).reject {|f| f.users.where(id: @user.id).present? }
```

Ugly and very expensive in terms of performance (many SQL queries). For details on reject check the details [HERE](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-reject-21)

Hope somebody finds a more elegant and efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Article.joins(:comments).group('article.id').having('count(comments.id) =0')
```

Comment: Ok dude - next time i will

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to article class

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_no_comments_by(user)
    includes(:comments).
      references(:comments).
      where.not(comments: { user_id: user.id })
  end
end
```